# How to change the resolution/size of iMovie so I can export square videos for Instagram?

Tags: imovie

Looking to change the resolution dimensions to a square. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You might crop each slide.  I haven't looked but if you have a lot of slide thee might be a way to set the crop as a 'default'